# Using Routing or State?

Tags: reactjs

I've been working with React for the last 2 years in different projects, both had different approaches with React that made me think if I was using it correctly.

Let's imagine we want to create a game which has 3 views:

- 1st view: difficulty selection
- 2nd view: the game
- 3rd view: game over screen with your stats.

The first pattern would use state/props to know which view you need to render. Here's some pseudocode:

```
const view = {
 settings: <Settings/>,
 game: <Game/>,
 stats: <Stats/>,
}
return view[this.props.view]
```

The second approach would use history to route you into the views:

```
 history.push("/game/settings")
 history.push("/game/playing")
 history.push("/game/stats")
```

Both ways are working but they are really different. My question is: Which one is better? and the most important: Why?

Answer (score 1):

Both approach has its own pros and cons.

We should use first pattern when we want

- Conditional rendering of components.
- Components should not render directly by url.

We should use second pattern in below scenarios:

- You can do route level chunking with second approach. Which will reduce your JS bundle size on first loading. Hence fast game loading time.
- suppose you want to share your game stat page. Is you have separate route, You can share via url with first approach its quite difficult.

---